# open (display) pdf files in Sikuli

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

I want to open (display) in adobe reader pdf files from my directory of pdf files in Sikuli. 
I manage to do this for one file:

```
import os
import subprocess 

file = 'C:/Users/.../pdf/test3.pdf'
subprocess.Popen([file],shell=True)
```

This works fine.

Now, I want to do this for each pdf file in my directory.
Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import subprocess 

source = 'C:/Users/.../pdf'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        subprocess.Popen([file],shell=True)
```

But it is not working. Can someone plase help me to get the `for` statement right?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import subprocess 

source = 'C:/Users/.../pdf'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
            subprocess.Popen([pdf_fullpath],shell=True)
```

You need to provide fullpath of pdf file, not just the filename.

Comment: If you find my answer is helpfull, please  upvote and check it as accepted answer. Thanks :)